# Edit iframe dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to edit the size of dinamic content generated on external url.
There's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="movie">
    <iframe name="ifr" id="ifr" src="http://zeyu.ucoz.es/directvenvio.html" width="100%" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

In this source url, there are 2 scripts, that generate an iframe,

I'm trying to change the **width** and **height** of this line:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
 width=620, 
 height=382, 
 channel='zeyudirtc', 
 g='1';
</script>
```

This is what i'm trying:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ifr').ready(function(){
        $('#ifr').contents().find('script').html('width=960, height=480, channel="zeyudirtc" ');
    });
});
</script>
```

But this doesn't work.

Can help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot access cross domain iframe content using javascript/jQuery if the iframe itself doesn't handle any way to communicate with parent window

Comment: Oh, ok, I will search another source :/
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the iframes source, it is possible. 
You will have to add Javascript Code to the iframe Content and the surrounding page.

The code you need inside the iframe Content should be like this:

First get the height, the iframe needs.

```
var height = getDocHeight();
    var height = $("html").height();
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
    if(msie > 0){
        height = Math.max(
        document.documentElement["clientHeight"],
        document.documentElement["scrollHeight"],
        document.body["scrollHeight"]
        );
    }
```

Then you have to send a message to the surrounding page. Like this:

```
parent.postMessage(height, "DomainOfTheSurroundingPage");
```

That's it for the iframe.

On the other site you need to listen to the messages.

```
 if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener ("message", receiveMessage, false);        
} else {
    if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent("onmessage", receiveMessage, false);
    }
}

function receiveMessage(event)
{       
  var height = event.data; 
  do something();
}
```

Now you have the height (in px) to work with. 
Wrap the iframe in a div.

```
Div
  --- iframe
```

Then set the height of your wrapper div to 0 and the padding bottom to the height you submitted.

That should do the trick.

If you cannot add the code to the iframe Content however you can't edit the height and width of the iframe dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Check css "!important" value. In css this is a "high level"

```
#ifr {
    height: 1000px!important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mraranturnik/4vqhLdpq/

Comment: This change the iframe height only, but the player are not resizing.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is not a problem script or iframe but movi url. In url you have player size. If you want change player size you mast do somthing this

```
var playerUrl = $('#ifr').contents().find('iframe').attr('src');
```

Next write RegExp for url and put new src value for iframe in file :)

Your solution change only iframe size not a player size

[image: In url you have player size]